# Asynchronously Open A New Tab Programmatically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Using javascript how can I quickly open a new tab(s) without relinquishing execution? Like opening a background tab?

```
window.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
```

Is really slow, and actually when I do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    window.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank")
}
```

We only get one tab, the execution stops? Is there anyway to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Pop up blockers are going to hate it

Comment: What you are doing is the way to do it. But, depending on how your code is initiated, popup blockers may prevent it. In order to get around popup blockers, you need to have your code be initiated from a user action, like a button click and not just automatically execute and you need to limit the amount of new tabs. There is rarely a valid situation that requires more than 2 tabs to open.

Comment: I'm not trying to create a user facing website functionality. I'm making script that uses a headless webdriver to scrape many websites at once, I can execute a script from my main control method but if I want to open a new tab for each script execution there is loads of time wasted in overhead of the driver call instead of just opening like 10 tabs at once.

Comment: @ScottThompson then use a headless software built for that. Because you won't be able to do that.

Comment: Yeah, it's really slow though. Each script execution has a lot of overhead. I'm sure it's possible to do in one script, really I can't see why it wouldn't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that finds this I found a solution by using a chrome extension which opens the tabs in the background.

You can include extensions even in headless drivers so you will need to also research that.